# ADOdb executing query don't work

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb

I try to connect to datebase with odbc_mssql driver:

```
$kpp_db = ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
$kpp_db->debug = true;
$kpp_db->charSet="UTF-8";
$kpp_dbDSN = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$kppConfig_dbHost;Database=$kppConfig_dbName;";
$kppConfig_akEnabled=$kpp_db->Connect($kppConfig_dbDSN, $kppConfig_dbLogin, $kppConfig_dbPassword);
```

Then i try to execute some query:

```
kpp_db->Exequte($quer);
```

In result i get the message 'Missing extension for odbc'. What can be wrong?

UPD: I install php5-odbc package and now message is 
    IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Comment: You're missing the extension.  Enable it in `php.ini`.

Comment: What is an extension?
If I understand correctly, adodb himself must connect their extensions. Or not?